# Align mfc controls

Tags: mfc

I want to create a dialog where every box is the same size and has the same margin between each other. Is it possible to do this in the editor or do I have to go to the code behind?
As you can see on the image there is different spacing between the controls.(I am using VS 2010 if that matters)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the Dialog Editor tools to do that. That's what they're there for.

Select the first column of controls and choose "Space Evenly Down" either from from (a) the Format menu or (b) the Dialog Editor toolbar.

For the second column you can either do the same, or as I prefer, for each row select the two controls and use the "Align Bottoms" tool to make sure both columns are vertically aligned.

See the [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kccdh60b.aspx) on this sort of thing.

Comment: That works but not here because OP wants the controls to be very close, for example 1 pixel separation. But dialog unit is not equal to pixel, so the first separation is 1 pixel, but the next separation will be 2 pixel. It has to be done programmatically to force all the separation to be 1 pixel.

Comment: When moving controls using the arrows on the keyboard, it moves 2 pixels. Can I change that somehow so it only moves one pixel each time?